# Django count distinct number of related model

Tags: django

Consider the following models:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    num_awards = models.IntegerField()

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pages = models.IntegerField()
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, related_name='related_books')
```

From a `Publisher` instance how can I get the number of book by distinct value on `pages` field? For example:

```
| name      | pages | publisher |
|-----------|-------|-----------|
| Golden    | 20    | 1         |
| Grey      | 23    | 1         |
| Blue      | 20    | 1         |
| Grotesque | 27    | 2         |
```

If I have `publisher = Publisher.objects.get(id=1)` how can I achieve something like this:

```
# equals to 2 [Golden, Grey]
publisher.related_books.all().distinct('pages').count()
```

Comment: So, "equals to 2 for Golden and Blue" is the expected output?

Comment: @PabloPalácios, sorry for Golden and Grey I meant. Fixed it.

Comment: Actually things got worse to me now. Do you want to know how many books one have with different pages? I mean, why grey should return 2?

Comment: @PabloPalácios, Yes. I want to count the books that do not have the same number of pages.

Comment: Because `Golden` and `Grey` have different number of pages and they belong to `Publisher 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, you just need to [restrict returned `values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values), like so:

```
publisher.related_books.all().values('pages').distinct('pages').count()
```

This will just give you the number of different page lengths for a publisher, but not the associated books for each page length. To do that you'd probably need an extra query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want reusable queries, you could do this:

```
class BookQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def by_publisher(self, publisher):
         return self.filter(publisher=publisher)

    def distinct_number_of_pages(self):
         return self.distinct(pages)

class Book(...):
    ...
    objects = BookQuerySet.as_manager()


class Publisher(...):

    @property 
    def number_of_page_lengths(self):
         return Book.objects.by_publisher(self).distinct_number_of_pages().count()
```